# Invalid chars in Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

I found a bug in .Net running on Windows XP. The string value of `Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName` or `Screen.AllScreens[]` contains extra characters at the end (nulls and garbage from memory buffer). The problem does not exist in Windows 7. The question is - is there Windows Update (KB) which fixes this?

Try this (on XP):

```
Text = string.Format("{0}: {1}",
       Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName.Length, 
       Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName);
```

Usually the result is: `31: \\.\DISPLAY1`. The correct length is 12 instead of 31. There is `\0`after `Display1` and for that reason the string looks OK, but for string comparisons it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is bug in .Net/XP which is not fixed with Windows update. My solution is this:

```
string dev = Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName;
int eos = dev.IndexOf( '\0' );
if ( eos != -1 )
  dev = dev.Substring( 0, eos );
```